# Set of feature points and Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**For some $n\in \mathbb N$, what is the set of points**

$$\{\underline y=[\sin(x), \sin(2x),\dots \sin(nx)]^T,\ x\in [0,2\pi)\}?$$

The question naturally arises in the field of Fourier analysis, where the value of any ODD function is approximated by

$$f(x)\approx \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\sin(ix)=\langle \underline a,  [\sin(x), \dots \sin(nx)]^T\rangle,$$

where $\underline a = [a_1, \dots a_n]^T$ are the Fourier coefficients.

For $n=2$, this set can be represented in the plane. I tried to plot it for 10k values of $x$ and this is what I got

[image: Points of the curve]

Comment: What do you want besides the description: $\{\underline y=[\sin(x), \sin(2x),\dots \sin(nx)]^T,\ x\in [0,2\pi)\}$?

Comment: Has it got a name? Its properties are objective of research?

Comment: I don't know if it has a name. In $n=2$ it's an example of a figure 8 (for the obvious reason). Not all figure 8 are of this form though.